# Q React boilerplate how to remove .bin extension from the emitted .htaccess.bin file

Tags: webpack, react-boilerplate

I'm using [react boilerplate](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate) and when I run the build script "npm run build" npm executes the following command

webpack --config internals/webpack/webpack.prod.babel.js --color -p --progress --hide-modules --display-optimization-bailout

This builds the application and emits all the files to the build folder.

I have an .htaccess file in my source now when the the app is build somewhere in the build process the .htaccess file gets a .bin extension and it is emitted as .htaccess.bin

how can I prevent the build process adding the .bin extension to the .htaccess file?

Comment: which boilerplate are you using?

Comment: https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer was provided in [github issue](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/issues/2296) of react boilerplate. This issue has been fixed in the latest build of [react-boilerplate](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate).

Anyways, if you want to fix the issue, change the import of `.htaccess` in `app.js` to as follows

> import 'file-loader?name=.htaccess!./.htaccess';

See the fixed `app.js` file in [github repo of react boilerplate](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/blob/master/app/app.js#L28)